# Sieve of Eratosthenes solution for CodeEval

Tags: python, programming-challenge, sieve-of-eratosthenes

The code below takes integer n as input, and delivers a list of all primes up to integer n using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

My question is, could you please help me optimize this code? Is it considered poor code to use 'try' flow control? I'd like to optimize the code such that I don't need it.

```
def factorfinder(n):
    A = range(0,n+1)
    for i in xrange(0,int(math.sqrt(n))):
        if i == 0 or i == 1:
            A[i] = 0
            continue
        for j in xrange(0,n):
            try:
                A[i**2+j*i] = 0
            except IndexError:
                pass
    return filter(lambda x: x != 0, A)
```

Comment: Another optimization you can do. Beyond initial conditions (i.e. 1,2,3), primes are _only_ found at `i = 6k-1` or `i = 6k+1`. See: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html So, you only need test 5,7,11,13,17,19,23,25,29,31,...

Comment: This is not going to work for 25, you should use `int(math.sqrt(n))+1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statement can be moved out of the loop, if you do you need to change the range to start at 2.

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 0
for i in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
```

For your other loop, we can think of the algorithm slightly differently.
You start at `i ** 2`, you take a step of `i`, and it ends on `len(A)` (shown by the try-except).
Or:

```
for j in xrange(i ** 2, n + 1, i):
```

As for `filter` you can change it to use `bool` or `None` instead of the lambda.
Alternately you can change it to a list comprehension:

```
return [i for i in A if i != 0]
```

This makes the code simple:

```
def factorfinder(n):
    A = range(n + 1)
    A[0] = 0
    A[1] = 0
    for i in xrange(2, int(math.sqrt(n))):
        for j in xrange(i ** 2, n + 1, i):
            A[j] = 0
    return filter(bool, A)
```

Comment: Thanks Joe for the supremely helpful advice. I'm already applying it to another similar problem I'm working on.

Comment: You could use `filter(bool, A)` instead of `filter(lambda x: x != 0, A)`

Comment: @zondo Yes you could, I'll edit that in a bit

Comment: @zondo, @JoeWallis: or just `filter(None, A)` which does the same.

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus I didn't know that, but IIRC Guido doesn't like `map`, `filter` and `reduce` and so wanted to remove them in Py3, so using a comprehension is probably better/safer.